# Out of Process COM Server and Event Handling

Tags: vb.net, com, out-of-process

As I'm working on making an out of process VB COM Server to use it in a client VB application, and bring stability to the application.

The following link of sample code from MSDN helped me in the making of VB COM server, and I successfully exposed Methods, Properties and Events from that COM Server. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBExeCOMServer-a5b9f49f

I've used the COM Server in client application using following code, it worked fine for Properties and Functions calls, however, when I tried to handle an event exposed by the COM Server I get a compile time error:

```
Dim obj = CreateObject("MeridiaAPICOMServer.BaseControllerSimple")
obj.TestProperty = "test" // worked fine
obj.TestFunction() // worked fine
AddHandler obj.TestEvent, AddressOf TestEventHandlerFunction
```

// **Compile Time Error!!!** TestEventis not an event of 'Object'

To resolve this compile time error, I tried type casting the Object type to 'BaseControllerSimple' type using following code but with that change, I get an exception at runtime:

```
Dim obj As BaseControllerSimple = CreateObject("MeridiaAPICOMServer.BaseControllerSimple")
```

// **EXCEPTION!** Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'MeridiaAPICOMServer.BaseControllerSimple'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

Later, I tried making an interface in COM Server's code and made "BaseControllerSimple" class to implement that interface. Here is the code snippet for the interface and the class implementing it:

```
<ComImport(), ComVisible(True), _
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), _
Guid("0742da3d-1cfa-4a3d-a104-35dbecb4ea48")> _
Public Interface IBaseControllerSimple

<DispId(1)> Event TestEvent(ByVal portName As String, ByVal baseID As Long)
<DispId(2)> Sub TestFunction()
<DispId(3)> Property TestProperty() As String

End Interface
```

Following is the code for the IBaseControllerSimple class

```
<ComClass(BaseControllerSimple.ClassId, BaseControllerSimple.InterfaceId, BaseControllerSimple.EventsId), ComVisible(True)> _
Public Class BaseControllerSimple
    Inherits ReferenceCountedObject
    Implements IBaseControllerSimple
Public Const ClassId As String _
= "9b5a0579-4f03-4a48-8d29-79dbbdbd32a9"
Public Const InterfaceId As String _
= "0742da3d-1cfa-4a3d-a104-35dbecb4ea48"
Public Const EventsId As String _
= "496a6535-4d44-4ee2-be02-ed69938e799b"

' These routines perform the additional COM registration needed by 
' the service.

<ComRegisterFunction(), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> _
Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal t As Type)
    Try
        COMHelper.RegasmRegisterLocalServer(t)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message) ' Log the error
        Throw ex ' Re-throw the exception
    End Try
End Sub

<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), ComUnregisterFunction()> _
Public Shared Sub Unregister(ByVal t As Type)
    Try
        COMHelper.RegasmUnregisterLocalServer(t)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message) ' Log the error
        Throw ex ' Re-throw the exception
    End Try
End Sub

 Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub

Public Event TestEvent(ByVal portName As String, ByVal baseID As Long) _
    Implements IBaseControllerSimple.TestEvent

// TestFunction and TestProperty are also implemented and defined here...
End Class
```

After defining an interface, I tried following code:

```
Dim obj As IBaseControllerSimple = CreateObject("MeridiaAPICOMServer.BaseControllerSimple")
```

// **EXCEPTION** Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IBaseControllerSimple'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{0742DA3D-1CFA-4A3D-A104-35DBECB4EA48}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Looking forward to a solution, or any kind of feedback that would help me resolve the problem of handling events which are exposed by a VB COM Server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quote: "Additional registry keys and values are required for the COM server.".  The exception says that you did not do this correctly.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Can you please help me identify the correct way of doing this? I've already tried different things but I still believe there is something missing that's causing these exceptions.